# Rails app connecting to MS SQL Server Express on another server

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have developed an application using SQLite (as provided). I've renamed all the columns to fit with the SQL that is running on another server, but cannot get it to connect and to populate with the server database.

My database.yml file looks like this:

```
production: 
adapter: mysql2
host: *IP*
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
pool: 5
username: *user*
password: *pwd*
database: *DB name*
```

The IP I use to connect to the server is different to that of the IPv4 address of it, but I've tried both.

I've commented out:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

and replaced it with

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
```

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL is one dbms product, and MS SQL Server Express is another. But what's MySQLExpress?

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant - MS SQL Server Express